# Convergence of Sequence without $a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The sequence ${a_n}$ is defined by $a_1=2$, and

$a_{n+1}= {1\over2}(a_n+{2\over{a_n}})$ for $n≥1$. Assuming $a_n$ converges, find its limit.

I've found that the limit is $\sqrt2$ just by plugging a couple points, but not sure how to figure this out without plotting points (ie. by taking $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$) but I can't seem to figure out a formula for $a_n$ either.

Comment: Just pass to limit in the recurrence formula.

Comment: We assume $a_n$ converges. That is $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ (without specifying $a$). Now let's plug in $a$ in $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(a_n + \frac{2}{a_n})$ and solve for $a$. What do you oberserve? How could that be helpful?